# Displaying vertical images with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

If you look [here](http://isskin.codejock.com/visualstyles.asp) it shows a vertical image on the left. Example:

[image: Sample with vertical image]

Now, I have the entries in my `[Setup]` section:

```
WizardImageFile=compiler:wizmodernimage-is.bmp
WizardSmallImageFile=compiler:wizmodernsmallimage-is.bmp
```

Yet for me, I never get images showing on the left:

[image: No Vertical]

Has the vertical image been dropped? I verify the files are in the compiler folder.

Comment: This might have duplicated answer but mine is more thorough IMHO.

Comment: True. Consider posting your answer to the original question.

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: Just post it there.

Comment: Done.  I added it.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Do I then delete this question? I would lose reputation though ...

Comment: It's ok, keep it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [answer](http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=105812&group=jrsoftware.innosetup#105812). It states:

> The `WizardImageFile` is shown on the **Welcome** and **Finish** pages.  However, the Welcome page is *skipped by default* now (see `DisableWelcomePage`), so it will normally only be visible on the Finished page.  (This is enabled by default, but it is possible that you disabled that too -- see `DisableFinishedPage`.)
>
> The `WizardSmallImageFile` is shown on all other pages.

That explains why I can’t see the images. Wonder why the **Welcome** Page is off by default?

I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn742479.aspx) which states:

> **Don't use Welcome pages—make the first page functional whenever possible.** Use an optional Getting Started page only when:
>
> - The wizard has prerequisites that are necessary to complete the wizard successfully.
> - Users may not understand the purpose of the wizard based on its first Choice page, and there isn't room for further explanation.
> - The main instruction for Getting Started pages is "Before you begin:".

Comment: Plus 1 for the MSDN reference. (But please don't use JPG for non-photographic images!)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I will fix that later.